# How might I arrange data by common year row into separate columns in R?

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R but have worked with dplyr for data transformation.

I have a data frame with rows for year and a number.

```
row     year    int

1       2020    100
2       2020    150
3       2020    300
4       2020    750
5       2020    555
6       2019    179
7       2019    233
8       2019    399
9       2019    400
10      2019    543
```

How might I group these rows by common year, in row order, but organized into columns? Such as:

```
year    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5

2020    100     150     300     750     555
2021    179     233     399     400     543
```

This should be simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with dplyr or base R. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a sequence column by 'year' and then pivot to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    dplyr::select(-row) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(new = str_c('col', row_number())) %>%  
    ungroup %>%  
    pivot_wider(names_from = new, values_from = int)
# A tibble: 2 x 6    
#   year  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1  2020   100   150   300   750   555
#2  2019   179   233   399   400   543
```

---

Or with `data.table`, `rowid` does the sequence creator and this can be passed into the formula interface of `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1),  year ~ paste0('col', rowid(year)), value.var = 'int')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(row = 1:10, year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), int = c(100L, 150L, 
300L, 750L, 555L, 179L, 233L, 399L, 400L, 543L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thank you once again @akrun, that's very helpful and works perfect using the tidyverse.

Comment: Could you tell me one last step, how do I remove the column "Year" after we are done? I tried ` select(df1, -Year)` but it kept the Year column there.

Comment: @JacksonWalker there is a group attribute, which I removed with `ungroup`, now, it should work with `select`

Comment: @akrun I have a question about your solution what is the purpose of `dplyr::select(-row)`?  I am getting the following error `"This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet."` Also, I can remove that line without impacting the output.

Comment: @sachin2014 the column 'row' was not needed, so it was removed wiith `select`.  Not able to reproduce that error